# I get a constant for the whole raster by subtracting two rasters in R and QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, r

I have two raster in brick format, as a result of previous operations, they have the same characteristics. When I try to make a simple subtraction between the two, it gives me a constant in all my study area. when I do other operations like multiply, add or divide it works perfectly, but not with subtraction. Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

reading the previous queries I have tried replacing NA values, with different raster formats and nothing. the input values of the subtraction are obtained by different functions.

```
Rtoa_B1 <- Rtoa_F(d, RadianceB1, Eo,Us)
Rsuperf_B1 <- Rsuperf_F(RadianceB1,Lr1,Tv,Eo,d,Oz,Tz,Edown)
Ratm <- Rtoa_B1 - Rsuperf_B1
```

the classes of the obtained files are

```
> Rtoa_B1
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 118, 111, 13098, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.004500776, 0.004518253  (x, y)
extent     : -75.7172, -75.21762, 5.978564, 6.511717  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +a=6378137 +rf=298.25722293287 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : B1_MOD02HKM.A2019001.1605.061.2019002013822 
min values :                                  0.08510739 
max values :                                   0.3040431 

> Rsuperf_B1
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 118, 111, 13098, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.004500776, 0.004518253  (x, y)
extent     : -75.7172, -75.21762, 5.978564, 6.511717  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +a=6378137 +rf=298.25722293287 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : B1_MOD02HKM.A2019001.1605.061.2019002013822 
min values :                                   0.0617993 
max values :                                    0.280735 

> Ratm
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 118, 111, 13098  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.004500776, 0.004518253  (x, y)
extent     : -75.7172, -75.21762, 5.978564, 6.511717  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +a=6378137 +rf=298.25722293287 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0.02330808, 0.02330808  (min, max)
```

the functions

```
Rsuperf_F <- function(radiance,Lr,Tv,Eo,d,Oz,Tz,Edown){
  
  return((pi*(radiance-Lr)*(d**2))/(Tv*((Eo*cos(Oz)*Tz)+Edown)))
}
Rtoa_F <- function(d,radiance,Eo,Us){
  
  return(  (pi*(d**2)*radiance)/(Eo*Us)   )
}
```

function values are previously calculated

Comment: Not sure we can do much without either your data or some more information about the objects in your R session. What constant value are you getting? What are the values in the raster cells? Does `Rtoa_B1[1,1] - Rsuperf[1,1]` not equal `Ratm[1,1]`?

Comment: thanks for answering. the constant value I get is the subtraction of the minimum values (0.0212086). raster cell values are in the range (0 - 1). No, they are not the same. what seems very strange to me is that all arithmetic operations work except subtraction. the files are of type:> class(Rtoa_B1)
[1] "RasterBrick"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"

Comment: Can you use the "edit" link on your question to add the extra information - and show us the output of `print(Rtoa_B1)` and `print(Rsuperf_B1)` and `print(Ratm)` so we can see what the size and structure of these stacks are. Also where does the `Rsuperf_F` function come from?

Comment: Of course, ta edit it. In theory it should give a raster of positive values between (0.1 - 0.9)

Comment: This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66844870/i-get-a-constant-for-the-whole-raster-by-subtracting-two-rasters-in-r

Answer (score 0):

the raster data is different but their differences with respect to the other are the same, never imagine that because the functions are affected by some different variables. I will review the methodology. Thank you for your attention.